# 'snyk-scm-contributors-count' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: bitbucket, snyk

I have **Synk CLI** installed on my local and yet `snyk-scm-contributors-count` is not found.
I haven't found the correct documentation for it. Trying to see if anyone else having similar issues.

Comment: Hi Makanist, could you share how you installed it?
The command to install it is `npm i -g snyk-scm-contributors-count`
can you share the exact message you get saying it is not found? Using the -g will make the install global so it can be run from any folder
This is the doc explaining how to run it
https://docs.snyk.io/snyk-api-info/other-tools/snyk-scm-contributors-count-cli-tool/usage

Comment: You are 100% correct didn't use -g "global" to install it previously. But its the same user trying to use it. May be the cmd/gitbash on the the Visual Studio Code command pallets comes up as some random users. However, this issue is solved. Thanks @Jonathan Gruber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the final answer:
Installing this way is the proper way
`npm i -g snyk-scm-contributors-count`